# Undefined control sequence using \rowcolor, \cellcolor and \multicolumn (packages already installed)

Tags: tables, multirow, rowcolor, cellcolor

I am using https://www.tablesgenerator.com in order to create my table. The code is:

```
% Please add the following required packages to your document preamble:
% \usepackage{multirow}
% \usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
% If you use beamer only pass "xcolor=table" option, i.e. \documentclass[xcolor=table]{beamer}
\begin{table}[]
\begin{tabular}{|c|l|l|}
\hline
\rowcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF} 
{\color[HTML]{000000} \textbf{Based on}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}{\color[HTML]{000000} \textbf{Name}}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}{\color[HTML]{000000} \textbf{Description}}} \\ \hline
                                         & block.coinbase                                                                    & Address of the miner who mined the current block                                         \\ \cline{2-3} 
                                         & block.difficulty                                                                  & Relative measure of how difficult it was to find the block                               \\ \cline{2-3} 
                                         & block.gaslimit                                                                    & Maximum gas consumption for transactions within the block                                \\ \cline{2-3} 
                                         & block.number                                                                      & Height of current block                                                                  \\ \cline{2-3} 
\multirow{-5}{*}{Block variable}         & block.timestamp                                                                   & When the block was mined                                                                 \\ \hline
                                         & block.blockhash(block.number)                                                     & Blockhash of the current block                                                           \\ \cline{2-3} 
                                         & block.blockhash(block.number - 1)                                                 & Blockhash of the last block                                                              \\ \cline{2-3} 
\multirow{-3}{*}{Blockhash}              & block.blockhash()                                                                 & Blockhash of a block that is at least 256 blocks older than the current one              \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

I have already installed the packages mentioned above: `{multirow}` and `[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}`. Despite this, I am getting errors at `\rowcolor`, `\cellcolor` and `\multirow`. Does anyone know what could be causing this error? Am I missing something?

[image]

Comment: `I am using https://www.tablesgenerator.com i`  that site seems to come up a lot, I don't really understand why, the input to it isn't really any easier than than the latex markup and it seems to generate over-complicated code.  The error message is saying you have not loaded the color or colortbl packages, so presumably that is the case despite your title saying they are loaded. Please show a test file that loads these packages and produces the error shown

Comment: Remove the `%` from `% \usepackage{multirow}`  and
`% \usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor]` and the code will compile OK.

Comment: I've imported in another file. I tried this example in an empty project and it's working. Dunno what's the problem here. I'm gonna check it out carefully. Tysm.